# Touch event Cocos2d iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have doubts about touch event in cocos2d, in particular:
I have two layers:

```
GameLayer.m



-(id)init
        {
           if(self=[super init])
           {

           NSLog(@"GAME");

           CCSprite*game=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"alien.png"];
           CGSize size=[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
           self.contentSize=CGSizeMake(50,50);
           self.touchEnabled=YES;
           game.position=CGPointMake(40,40);
           [self addChild:game];
           //NSLog(@"%d",[[self children] count]);
           //NSLog(@"%f",self.position.x);
            }
            return self;
        }
    -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
       NSLog(@"GAME");
    }



UserInterfaceLayer.m


    -(id)init
            {

               if(self=[super init])
               {

                  NSLog(@"USER");
                  self.touchEnabled=YES;
                  CCSprite*game=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spiders.png"];
                  CGSize size=[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
                  self.contentSize=CGSizeMake(20,20);
                  game.position=CGPointMake(40,40);
                  [self addChild:game];
                  //NSLog(@"%d",[[self children] count]);
                  //NSLog(@"%f",self.position.x);

               }

               return self;

            }


        -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
        {
           NSLog(@"USER");
        }
```

Both are children of one scene:

```
MultiLayerScene.m

-(id)init
{
    if(self=[super init])
    {
       sharedMultiLayerScene = self;
       self.contentSize=CGSizeMake(30, 30);

       CGSize size=[CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;


       // The GameLayer will be moved, rotated and scaled independently
       GameLayer* gameLayer = [GameLayer node];
       gameLayer.position=CGPointMake(250,250);
       [self addChild:gameLayer z:1 tag:1];
       //gamelayerposition = gameLayer.position;



       // The UserInterfaceLayer remains static and relative to the screen area.
       UserInterfaceLayer* uiLayer = [UserInterfaceLayer node];
       uiLayer.position=CGPointMake(-100, -100);
       [self addChild:uiLayer z:-1 tag:2];


    }
   return self;
}
```

My problem is that I touch on screen at any position their ccTouchesBegan event run.
For example if I touch only on GameLayer runs both the GameLayer touches event and the other.
I try also to insert the two layer in two different position(as you can see from the code) , but the problem still persist.
How Do I resolve this problem?
I would like ,for example,if I touch on Gamelayer respond only its touch event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

Priority: lower number = higher priority.

Comment: Ok thank you Haroon you resolve me the problem,but I don't understand one thing: Do you explain me why(the scene is 30x30(small))if I touch at any point of screen run the touch event of layers?(without your solution)

Comment: I tried, to retrieve the `boundingbox` of CCScene and layer it was CGRectZero not any other value, So not sure why it was 30 X 30 because  What I know is `CCScene` and `CCLayer` both don't have `boundingbox`.